# Python - convert numpy.nd array into dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have 20,000 arrays of type `numpy.ndarray` with length 4421 values in "ts". They look like this

```
array([0.33798802, 0.28742515, 0.3366694 , ..., 3.47222222, 28.90786312, 66.12929928])
```

their linked classes "class_id" are in another `numpy.ndarray` of this form

```
array([[2],
       [3],
       [2],
       ..., 
       [2],
       [2],
       [2]])
```

How can I merge both `numpy.ndarray` into a single dataframe with 20,000 rows and 4422 columns (where the last column are the classes from "class_id").

The output should be something like

```
  3.37988024e-01,   2.87425150e-01,   3.36669403e-01, 3.47222222e+00, ...,  2
  3.78449348e-01,   3.68259383e-01,   3.77523300e-01, 7.93650794e+00, ...,  3
  4.20835393e-01,   3.83079983e-01,   4.20191384e-01, 4.13223140e+00, ...,  2
```

Comment: Could you include the desired output based on a minimal sample (say 3 arrays with length 4?) and what has this to do with a dictionary?

Comment: `ts` is a dictionary or a list of arrays?

Comment: Both ts and class_id were extracted from a dictionary. However, they are numpy.ndarray type. Yes, ts is a list of arrays like `array([[  3.37988024e-01,   2.87425150e-01,   3.36669403e-01, ...,
          3.47222222e+00,   2.89078631e+01,   2.66129299e+02],
       [  3.78449348e-01,   3.68259383e-01,   3.77523300e-01, ...,
          7.93650794e+00,   7.49814148e+01,   3.39940867e+02],
       [  4.20835393e-01,   3.83079983e-01,   4.20191384e-01, ...,
          4.13223140e+00,   3.17110530e+01,   3.13224462e+02],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list/array of numpy arrays (as `ts`) you could simply use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ts = [np.array([1,1,1,1]), np.array([2,2,2,2]), np.array([3,3,3,3])]
class_id = np.array([[4], [5], [6]])
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([ts, class_id], axis=1))
#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0  1  1  1  1  4
# 1  2  2  2  2  5
# 2  3  3  3  3  6
```

If your `ts` is a dictionary and you have some more complex "join" or "concatenation" behavior in mind this will be more complicated. But that should at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert. class_id appear as float. How can I convert it to integer? Another question, how can I subset rows depending on the class_id value?

Comment: @Ruser You can cast it to integer afterwards. Assuming you have the `DataFrame` saved as a variable called `df` it would be: In my example `df[4] = df[4].astype(int)` and in your case `df[4422] = df[4422].astype(int)`.

Comment: And how can I subset by class_id value @MSeifert? For instance, if df[4422]==1

Comment: You can use boolean indexing, e.g. `df[df[4422]==1]`.